# Kotlin - Error: Could not find or load main class in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

For this code

```
package com.virtualpairprogrammers.learningkotlin.kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

I get the error:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=54353:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/aniruddharavi/Downloads/PracticalsAndCode/End of chapter workspaces/chapter 2/LearningKotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/Users/aniruddharavi/Downloads/PracticalsAndCode/End of chapter workspaces/chapter 2/LearningKotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/Users/aniruddharavi/Downloads/PracticalsAndCode/End of chapter workspaces/chapter 2/LearningKotlin/lib/kotlin-test.jar:/Users/aniruddharavi/Downloads/PracticalsAndCode/End of chapter workspaces/chapter 2/LearningKotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar:/Users/aniruddharavi/Downloads/PracticalsAndCode/End of chapter workspaces/chapter 2/LearningKotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar com.virtualpairprogrammers.learningkotlin.kotlin.ExploringVariablesKt
Error: Could not find or load main class com.virtualpairprogrammers.learningkotlin.kotlin.ExploringVariablesKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.virtualpairprogrammers.learningkotlin.kotlin.ExploringVariablesKt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

on IntelliJ IDE.

I'm running a new Java project with Kotlin/JVM setting.

Comment: Hello, does the problem still reproduced? May be helpful: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22102

Answer (score 0):

Check the JVM settings in the project.  I had a similar problem until I set the target to 16, e.g.

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "16"
}
```